# escape character in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to access the data that I get in my json format i.e

```
"data": [{ "fieldData": { "articleId":"1a", "article.text.value":"test", "article.master::articlename": "test123" } }]
```

If I am doing `data.fieldData.articleId` I am getting the value but if I am not able to get the value for `article.text.value` and `article.master::articlename` by `data.fieldData.article.text.value` or `data.article.master::articlename`.

Comment: You would need to use bracket syntax to access properties that contain `.` or `::`

Comment: Thankyou so much! Its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
data.fieldData["article.text.value"]
```